# FireBase DatabaseReference function setValueAsync is not working in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add user in firebase database.
also I did added gradle file in code.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

Data Structure is like that.

users -> user_id -> user_pw

```
             -> user_name
             -> user_birth
             -> user_gender
```

Using Firebase page example. but it is not working.

Exactly setValueAsync is not working.

..Async function everything is not working.

code is.

```
public DatabaseReference userDB;
public Map<String, UserVO> users;

userDB  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
users = new HashMap<>();

users.put(user_id.getText().toString(), 
new UserVO(user_pw.getText().toString(), user_name.getText().toString(),
user_birth.getText().toString(),gender_checked.getText().toString()));

userDB.setValueAsync(users);
```

The error message is

> 'cannot resolve method 'setValueAsync...''

I also cannot find it in autocomplete..

Why doesn't this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for android:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
 .child(user_id.getText().toString())
 .setValue(new UserVO(user_pw.getText().toString(), user_name.getText().toString(),
 user_birth.getText().toString(),gender_checked.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: he is using this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#build_your_app

Comment: @PeterHaddad is he using Unity ?

Comment: @PeterHaddad in title 'in Android' writen

Comment: thank you for your guess. but I did insert data using other way. but I want to using this setValueAsync function ...

Comment: @김은지 I think you can add on complete listener so it is also async